# Set the password for PDF using UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile

Tags: iphone, pdf, passwords, pdf-generation, password-protection

I have successfully created the PDF file using UIKit method. but i am unable to set the password the created PDF. Please Help me. Advance thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [secure pdf : locked/uneditable to prevent changes after generating from iOS device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286732/secure-pdf-locked-uneditable-to-prevent-changes-after-generating-from-ios-devi)

Answer (score 0):

Please search before you ask - your question is clearly documented in the documentation from Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile

And there is an almost exact duplicate on StackOverflow:
[secure pdf : locked/uneditable to prevent changes after generating from iOS device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286732/secure-pdf-locked-uneditable-to-prevent-changes-after-generating-from-ios-devi)